# How to change mac address template for new LXC containers

Tags: networking, lxc

I'm running ubuntu 16.10.
I'd like to change the MAC address template used to allocate hw address to LXC containers.
I've modified `/etc/lxc/default.conf`, but I always get the default  `00:16:3e:xx:xx:xx` in my new containers.

I have also created a `/etc/lxc/lxc.container.conf` file with new `lxc.network.hwaddr = 12:23:45:00:00:xx`,
but it does not help either, even after reboot.

Any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks
Ray

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40876133/4594973